# Using SAS to calculate ROC information

Tags: sas

I have a set of sensor outputs, say a, b, or c. For each sensor observation, I also have a "ground truth" value of a, b, or c.

(I actually have 6 sensors and more outputs.)

I would like to create a table whose columns are Ground Truth (a, b, c)
with rows for sensor 1 through sensor 6. Each "cell" of this table will have a percentage of times sensor_i's output matches the ground truth. For example, if ground truth had three values of a, but sensor 1 reported a, a, and b for these three values, sensor 1 would have a value of 0.67 (2/3) in the a column of the table.

So for a series of observations in a .csv file like:

```
sensor,sensor_output,ground_truth
1,a,a
1,a,b
1,b,a
1,c,c
2,c,b
2,b,b
etc.,
```

Does anyone know how I can get the table I seek?
Thanks! Bruce

Comment: could you show an example of the table you would like to create from this input?

Comment: What approaches have you tried?